# How to find word and change only next second line word

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

The file name staff.txt and sample contents are:

```
JHON
MANAGER
10000
```

I want to find `JHON` in a file and I want to change whatever's in the 2nd line after that one with another word/number.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: is `10000` static text, or you want to change *whatever* is two lines below JHON?

Comment: Whatever below after two lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `sed` you can move to next line with `n`:

```
sed '/JHON/{n;n;s/.*/42/}'
```

Answer (score 8):

[Use ed, man!](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html)

```
ed -s staff.txt <<< $'/JHON/+2s/.*/4242\nw\nq'
```

This calls ed in scripting mode (`-s`) on the `staff.txt` file and sends it the following commands in an ANSI-quoted here-string:

- find the line containing `JHON` and go two lines beyond that (`+2`)
- on that line, search and replace anything and everything that's there (`.*`) with `4242`
- `w`rite the file out to disk
- `q`uit ed

The intermediate `\n`'s separate the various `ed` commands.

Alternatively, you could use the `c` command to change the line:

```
ed -s staff.txt <<< $'/JHON/+2c\n4242\n.\nw\nq'
```

Here, the replacement text needs to be entered separately (after) the `c` command, and ended with a period on its own (`\.\n`).

Comment: Rob Pike would [be proud](https://twitter.com/rob_pike/status/806220981106683904)!

Comment: The [succeeding comment on that post](https://twitter.com/fdiesch/status/806257997446049792) sounds like a new spin on [the old joke](https://twitter.com/iamdevloper/status/435555976687923200?lang=en): "I've been using ed for years, mostly because I can't figure out how to exit it."

Comment: When i am using this command
ed -s staff.txt <<< $'/JHON/+2s/.*/4242\nw\nq'
 Its working fine but in some case JHON word in a Bracket [ ].
at that time this command not working properly. Its changing some another word that start with [xyz ] 
example. 1)
ed -s staff.txt <<< $'/[JHON]/+2s/.*/4242\nw\nq'
 [JHON]
 [MANAGER]
[10000]

Its changing first bracket word in file not changing [JHON]

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'f{$0="newvalue";f=0}/JHON/{print;getline;f=1}1'
```

---

`f{$0="newvalue";f=0}` - If `f` is true set line to `newvalue` and reset `f` to `0`

`/JHON/{print;getline;f=1}` - If pattern `JHON` is found print it, print the next line, and set `f` to `1`

`1` - print

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `awk` solution:

```bsh
awk '/JHON/{c=0};(c!=""&&c++==2){$0="42"};{print};'
```

sets a counter `c` when `JHON` is found. Then, if `c` is set, increment and when `c==2`, change line (`$0`) to "42".

Answer (score 1):

if you have only one person (one register), you can use this code:

```
awk '/JHON/{print $0; getline; print "SUPERVISOR"; getline; print "99999"; }' staff.txt
```

If you `staff.txt` file has many persons (many registers) and you should replace only JHON data:

```
awk '/.*/{if($0=="JHON"){print $0; getline; print "SUPERVISOR"; getline; print "99999"; } else {print $0;}}' staff2.txt
```

Example of `staff2.txt`:

```
JHON
MANAGER
10000
ROGER
TEACHER
3000
ROBERT
SCIENTIST
20000
```

You should get this output:

```
JHON
SUPERVISOR
99999
ROGER
TEACHER
3000
ROBERT
SCIENTIST
20000
```

Another short way, to get the same output, could be:

```
awk '/JHON/{print;getline; print "SUPERVISOR"; getline; $0="99999"}1' staff2.txt
```

Explanation: if line is JHON, print JHON, go to the next line, print SUPERVISOR, go to the next line, replace it with 99999.
if line is NOT JHON, only print it.

Answer (score 0):

When I am using this command

```
ed -s staff.txt <<< $'/JHON/+2s/.*/4242\nw\nq'
```

Its working fine but in some case JHON word is in a `Bracket [ ]`
at that time this command not working properly. Its changing some another word that start with [xyz ]

example. 1)

```
ed -s staff.txt <<< $'/[JHON]/+2s/.*/4242\nw\nq'
[JHON]
[MANAGER]
[10000]
```

Its changing first bracket word in file not changing [JHON].

Comment: I think this is not an answer, you should write it as comment below the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484968/255251